# casting LPCWSTR to LPCSTR

Tags: c++, windows

got this code from a website that helped me in creating buttons and stuff. the buttons work but for some reason im getting an compiler error with the creating a static.

`cannot convert from 'const wchar_t [5]' to 'char'`

`cannot convert parameter 3 from 'char' to 'LPCWSTR'`

is there a simply way to fix this? i tried casting lyrics into another variable and making it just a char.

```
  static char *lyrics = TEXT("Dood");



switch (message)
{

case WM_CREATE:
{
       CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Beep"),    
                 WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                 20, 300, 80, 25,        
                 hWnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL);    

    CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Quit"),    
                 WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                 120, 300, 80, 25,        
                 hWnd, (HMENU) 2, NULL, NULL);    

     CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), lyrics, 
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT,
                20, 20, 300, 230,
                hWnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
static TCHAR *lyrics = TEXT("Dood");
```

With the compiler settings you appear to have, TCHAR will be converted to wchar_t.

Comment: awsome! thank you very much. this win32 stuff is very confusing to me.

Comment: Note that you're not actually casting anything.  You're just now using the correct types.

Comment: Also worth note, variable types T will resolve based on project settings of 'Unicode Vs Multi Byte Character Set(MBCS)'  as will the win32 functions which are wrapped in macros - ie CreateWindow macro is either CreateWindowA or CreateWindowW  and TCHAR is either char or wchar_t.