# I don't understand this error (LPCWSTR)

Tags: c++

Hi I am writing a code for a plants vs zombies trainer in C++ only when I tried to launch it, it failed with this error:

> error: cannot convert 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' to 'LPCSTR {aka const char*}' for argument '2' to 'HWND__* FindWindowA(LPCSTR, LPCSTR)'|

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    system("color 0A");//change the colour of the text
    cout << "PlantsVsZombies Trainer voor game of the year edition(gemaakt door Pjotr Slooff)" << endl;//display some (dutch) text
    cout << "Open PlantsVsZombies en druk dan op enter" << endl;
    system("Pause");//wait for the user to press enter
    LPCWSTR Game = L"Plants vs. Zombies";
    HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(0, Game);
    if (hwnd == 0)
    {
            cout << "PlantsVsZombies is niet gevonden open het en probeer het dan opnieuw" << endl;
            system("Pause");
    }
    else
    {
            DWORD process_ID;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &process_ID);
            HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, process_ID);
            cout << "PlantsVsZombies is gevonden! Happy Hacking :D" << endl;
            system("Pause");
            cout << "Typ 1 voor Zon Cheat" << endl;
            cout << "Typ: ";
            int Option;
            cin >> Option;
            if (Option > 1)
            {
                    cout << "Er is maar 1 optie" << endl;
                    system("Pause");
            }
            if (Option == 1)
            {
                    cout << "Hoeveel Zon wil je?" << endl;
                    cout << "Typ: ";
                    int Zon;
                    cin >> Zon;
                    DWORD newdatasize = sizeof(Zon);
                    if (WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)00005560, &Zon, newdatasize, NULL))
                    {
                            cout << "De Zon is toegevoegd" << endl;
                            system("Pause");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            cout << "Er was een error tijdens het toevoegen van de Zon" << endl;
                            system("Pause");
                    }

            }
    }
    main();
    return 0;
}
```

I find this very annyoing and I can't fix it so I will be really grateful for who answers my question

Comment: Windows is complaining that it cannot implicitly convert `LPCWSTR Game` to type `LPCSTR`, so you need to help the compiler out. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119222/casting-lpcwstr-to-lpcstr

Comment: Not related, but...[why-are-recursive-main-calls-not-allowed-in-c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326491/why-are-recursive-main-calls-not-allowed-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `FindWindowA(0, Game);` use `FindWindowW(0, Game);`, or simply `FindWindow`

`FindWindowA` accepts as in error LPCSTR arguments, and you are passing `LPCWSTR`.

Comment: Using only FindWindow may not work if he did not active Unicode in his IDE?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that **windows API's** usually come in two flavours :

1) **Ansi/Ascii** (legacy) which uses `char` as basetype for character
   - API functions ending with an **A** 
   - use `LPSTR` and `LPCSTR`

2) **Unicode** (native) which uses `wchar_t`  as basetype for character
   - API functions ending with a **W** 
   - use `LPWSTR` and `LPCWSTR`

You must decide which one to use with the appropiate argument types.
You can avoid many of these issues by using the 'neutral' versions of the API's:
These lack the **A** or **W** at the end of the names and are macro's that will be defined to either one of the actual API's
depending on the definition of the macro `UNICODE`.

The neutral version use the macro's `TCHAR` ,`LPTSTR` and `LPCTSTR`.
You should include **tchar.h** which gives you an API for manipulating 0-terminated **TSTR** data.

There's plenty info on this topic to be found by googling it.